# Retrieve generic object type when casted to base class

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have the following situation :

```
 public interface IBaseType
 {
      public void InterfaceMethod ()
 }

 public class MyType<T> : IBaseType
 {
    public void InterfaceMethod () {};
    public string DoSomething () 
    {  
       if ( typeof(T) == typeof(string) ) return "String";
       if ( typeof(T) == typeof(int) ) return "Int";
       ... so on
    }
 }

 List<IBaseType> list = new List<IBaseType> ();

 list.Add ( new MyType<int> () );
 list.Add ( new MyType<long> () );
 list.Add ( new MyType<string> () );
```

Now how can i retreive the correct generic when accessing to list elements ?

Example :

```
 IBaseType element = list[1] ;
 //here i would cast back element to MyType<long> type beacuse i would use method DoSomething()
```

Thanks in advance for help and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: `element.GetType()`? or provide a property which returns an enum of the concrete type so you can do an `if`...? but your list doesn't make sense, except for a global storage - why not push `DoSomething` to the interface, and implement the concrete processing to each implementation of `IBaseType`?

Comment: If you need a `MyType<long>` then cast to that...

Comment: Put DoSomething in your interface

Comment: If your DoSomething method is within IBaseType  declaration then you probably do not need to cast.

Comment: i have put DoSomething in derived class because the behavour change if T change, i need the interface only for few methods and for using a List<IBaseType> where i can place heterogeneous generics element.
So there is no way to get back right derived class istance with right generic inside using some automatic casting ? (i suppose that internally the object type never change when i assign it to List<IBaseType> isn't it?)

Comment: According to your code posted, `DoSomething` would be fine defined on the interface; it has no reference to T in its signature. You would still implement it in the concrete classes. Does it actually have input parameters of type T?

Comment: @Brannon i have edited my code to be more explicit, did you mean that if i put a base definition in IBaseType of DoSomething then i can call it over lists elements; and then actual method called is DoSomething of MyType<T> (because the actual type is MyType<T>) ?

Comment: There are fundamental problems with a generic class if it needs to cast to or check for specific types. Whatever you do you're going to struggle with this design problem.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I disagree that conditional code based on the type is always wrong. An easy one is math - I could know that I only have instances of `MyType<int>` and `MyType<double>`, both of which define a "+" operator, but no generic operation exists that lets me do `T + T` and get a result. Instead, the easiest solution is `if (T is int) { return (T)(object)((int)(object)a + (int)(object)b); }` (assuming `a` and `b` are both instances of `T`).

Comment: Yes, assuming that, what if I send you an object? or a Stream? Something that doesn't implement the + operator? But anyway, you're free to disagree, as am I :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to handle this is to add a `Type` property into `IBaseType`

```
public interface IBaseType
{
    void InterfaceMethod ();
    Type GenericType { get; }
}
```

Then, in your overridden class:

```
public class MyType<T> : IBaseType
{
    public Type GenericType { get { return typeof(T); }
}
```

You can also look up the Type of a generic class at run-time using [`Type.GetGenericArguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx), but that will involve the performance penalty of using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with commenter Lasse V. Karlsen: there is something fundamentally wrong with the design if you are doing explicit type-checking and conditionally executing code in a generic class (or any class, for that matter.

Without more context, it's hard to know for sure what you should be doing here. But it *seems* that you have a list of `IBaseType` instances, only some of which are types that implement `DoSomething()` (otherwise, that method would be in the interface, right?).

In that case, I think what you should do is introduce an intermediate type, from which all your explicitly-typed (i.e. *non-generic*) classes can inherit:

```
interface IBaseType { void InterfaceMethod(); }

abstract class MyType : IBaseType
{
    public void InterfaceMethod() { ...implementation here... }

    public abstract string DoSomething();
}
```

Then you'd have separate subclasses, one for each subtype:

```
class MyTypeInt32 : MyType
{
    public override string DoSomething() { return "Int32"; }
}

class MyTypeString : MyType
{
    public override string DoSomething() { return "String"; }
}

// etc.
```

Then you can do this:

```
IBaseType element = list[1];

MyType myTypeElement = element as MyType;

if (myTypeElement != null)
{
    string result = myTypeElement.DoSomething();
}
```

That would be the proper use of polymorphism. Note the almost-complete lack of special-case, type-specific code. The above just uses the type system itself to organize the type-specific logic.

Finally, I'll note that if it happens that the `InterfaceMethod()` is also a different implementation per-type, then you should just make an `IMyType` interface instead of the abstract class, since each type-specific class is where the actual interface implementation should go.

Comment: in my real case i need to represent a structure, where i place some constraint over type (for that reason i used generics), the list are the nested sctructures and is exposed by a getter of MyType.
This is because i need map some scheme format (XSD, C# code and other proprietary format) to a generic structure.
I am not using dynamics because i would like typechecking when i write each parser and because each element in my "meta schema" need to "remember" its type for future use.

Comment: @Skary: `dynamic` wouldn't help anyway, if you have some type-specific outcome you want. After all, at _some_ point, you'd still need to know the type. Unfortunately, your comment above doesn't really clarify anything with respect to the question itself. If polymorphism (as I illustrate above) doesn't address your question, then please edit your question in a way that unambiguously explains why you can't use polymorphism here.